# Too many arguments error without a reason

Tags: ti-nspire

I got this weird problem which I can not seem to solve. In a simple program like this:

```
Define hyp(a,b)=
Prgm
 disp √(a^(2)+b^(2))
EndPrgm
```

When calling the function with:

```
hyp(3,4)
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Too many arguments
```

Calling it like this:

```
hyp()
```

Results in:

```
Done
```

I have programms I coded in the past with the same code as above and they work as intended, but right now it just does not work for me.

Would be great if someone of you can help me out with this one.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I got the solution, apparently ctrl+s did not save the programm in the PC editor and i had to use ctrl+b to store the programm.

Answer (score 0):

Control + S saves it, Control + B stores it